# MATLAB replacing certain values of matrix with another matrix

Tags: matlab

I have an arbitrary matrix, `a = [1, 0, 0, 1]`.

I want to replace every 0 value with the values of another matrix `b = [1, 2, 3]`, and every 1 value with the value of yet another matrix `c  = [3, 4, 5]`.

I would therefore end up with the matrix `[3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]`.

I've tried finding the indices of the 0 and 1 values and replacing the values at those indices with b and c, but this isn't allowed since they aren't the same size. Is there any simple way of achieving this?

Comment: Will `b` and `c` always have the same size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 1];
b = [1, 2, 3];
c = [3, 4, 5];
```

Let's first take the arrays we want in the final matrix and put them in a cell array:

```
parts = {b, c}
parts =
{
  [1,1] =
     1   2   3
  [1,2] =
     3   4   5
}
```

The goal is to use the values of `a` as indices into `parts`, but to do that we need all of the values to be positive from 1 to some `n` (if there are missing values it'll take a bit more work). In this case we can just increment `a`:

```
a_inds = a + 1
a_inds =
   2   1   1   2
```

Now we can get a new cell array by doing `parts(a_inds)`, or a matrix by adding `cell2mat`:

```
result = cell2mat(parts(a_inds))
result =
   3   4   5   1   2   3   1   2   3   3   4   5
```

Comment: I was writing that :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I saw that and stole ur answer. Ninja muppet! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with a key:value map.

```
a = [1, 0, 0, 1];
b = [1, 2, 3];
c = [3, 4, 5];

keyset = [1,0];
valueset = {b,c};

mapobj = containers.Map(keyset,valueset);
new_vec = [];
for i =1:length(a)
    new_vec(length(new_vec)+1:length(new_vec)+length(mapobj(a(i))))= mapobj(a(i));
end
```

`1` is mapped to `b` and `0` mapped to `c`. The for loop iterates over `a` building an ever longer vector containing the mapped values.

This code will allow for non-sequential keys such that 37 could be added and mapped to another vector, whereas in the previous answer you would have to map `2` to the next vector in order for the code not to break.